# Isomorphism between finite groups with specific property is unique

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

I am looking for a clever justification for a statement I believe to be true. I would like to show that given an isomorphism, $\Phi$, between two finite groups, if it is known that $\Phi(a) = b$, then $\Phi$ is the $only$ isomorphism between the two groups that takes a to b.

The particular situation that brought me here was the question: If $\Phi$ is an isomorphism from $Z_{3} \oplus Z_{5} \to Z_{15}$, such that $\Phi(2,3) = 2$, deduce what element of $Z_{3} \oplus Z_{5}$ maps to 1.

I arrived at my solution fairly easily, my method was: find the generator (a,b) of $Z_{3} \oplus Z_{5}$ such that $(a,b)^2$ = (2,3), which yields (a,b) = (1,4) as the solution, but would also imply (or so it seems to me) that $\Phi$ is defined as

$$\Phi: (1,4)^k \mapsto k \hspace{2mm} \text{mod}(n).$$

But, I feel I cannot deduce that this is the $only$ answer unless I know that the isomorphism that carries (2,3) to 2, at least in this context, is unique. So I would like to get this justified simply to convince myself.

My thought is that if I were to suppose there was a different isomorphism that carried (2,3) to 2 the contradiction would surely have to arise in the supposed map being homomorphic.

Thanks

Comment: As soon as the domain of $\Phi$ has an automorphism $f$ distinct from the identity such that $f(a)=a$, then $\Phi\circ f$ is another isomorphism mapping $a$ to $b$. It is easy to construct examples of this. An extreme example is when $\Phi$ is the identity of a group $G$.  In general, there exist other automorphisms of $G$ which fix $a$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume $\Phi,\Psi\colon A\to B$ both map $a\mapsto b$. As $B$ is abealien in our case, we can simply consider $\Phi-\Psi$, whichmaps $a\mapsto 0$. Then $\langle a\rangle $ is in the kernel of $\Phi-\Psi$. Thus we can conclude that $\Phi$ is unique if this kernel is all of $A$. This is clearly the case if $\langle a\rangle=A$. It would already suffice if there is no normal subgroup containing $a$; but here $A$ is abelian as well, so everything is normal. However, it may happen that even if $A/\langle a\rangle$ is not trivial that there exists only the trivial homomorphism $A/\langle a\rangle \to B$. On the other hand, if a nontrivial  homomorphism $A/\langle a\rangle \to B$ exists, we can find different homomoprhisms $A\to B$ with $a\mapsto b$.

Comment: The jump from $a$ in the kernel implies <$a$> in the kernel is because we are under the assumption that $\Phi - \Psi$ is homomorphic? Thus ($\Phi - \Psi$)($a\cdot a$) = 0 \cdot 0, yes? @Hagen von Eitzen

Comment: Nevermind! I see it.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you again.